# Do classification trees need to consider the correlation between attributes?

Tags: classification, cart

In decision tree classification, we use the attribute that splits records, like entropy, as split nodes.

Does it need to consider the correlation between attributes?

Comment: Usually, the algorithms used will automatically take into accoiunt any feature correlations.

Comment: We know that `Bayes classifier` must use the independent attributes as input. Does `Decision tree` have the restrictions?

Comment: In addition, if we use dependent attributes in decision tree classification, the algorithm will automatically handle it? Can the entropy consider the correlation between attributes?

Answer (score -1):

Already asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62490/effect-of-features-that-are-highly-correlated-with-each-other-on-a-decision-tree)
Decision trees recursively partitions the input feature/attribute space to reduce the entropy/impurity score. The output on an unseen sample is obtained by finding the leaf node/ decision region containing the sample and calculating the majority class/label withing this leaf node. Here and in the original CART trees as well as the implementation in scikit-learn do the take into account the correlation between the attribute variables.

While we do know that this is taken care of by [random subspace selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_subspace_method) in random forests, which are an ensemble of decision trees. This consists of performing randomly subsampling the attributes without replacement.